# PYTHON Error after nplog "TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int "

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Maybe the problem is easy but I worked for hours to find the problem but I couldn't find any solution.

In the first part I build a dataframe taking data from [HERE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv). I had some problems to extract what I wanted (UK cumulative covid case day by day) but eventually I managed to get the right shape. My final dataframe size is 1 column x about 600 rows.

Now the code looks like this.

```
#BUILDING DATAFRAME

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)          
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv')
df=df[df["Country/Region"]=="United Kingdom"]
N = 11
df = df.iloc[N: , :]
df=df.drop(columns=["Province/State","Lat","Long","Country/Region"])
df = df.columns.to_frame().T.append(df, ignore_index=True)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
df=df.T
df = df.rename(columns={0: 'date', 1: 'nuovi_casi'})
df['nuovi_casi'] = df['nuovi_casi']+10000
M = 1
df = df.iloc[M: , :]
df=df.drop(columns=["date"]) 


#HERE IS THE PROBLEM

ts = df[['nuovi_casi']].dropna()
sts = ts.nuovi_casi
sts.index.name = None
ts_log = np.log(1+sts).dropna()
```

I had to add the line `df['nuovi_casi'] = df['nuovi_casi']+10000`  since my dataframe had some 0 values. So I listed all values and checked with another Python program to be sure and now my dataframe has all values above 10000.

When I run the code, the second part raises an error like this:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'log'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\\project_env\UK.py", line 69, in <module>
ts_log = np.log(1+sts).dropna()
File "C:\Users\\project_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 
1933, in __array_ufunc__
return arraylike.array_ufunc(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\\project_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 
274, in array_ufunc
result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*inputs, **kwargs)
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int which has no 
callable log method
```

Then I re-checked all values but they are all positive and the values are not that high since a similar code (which works perfeclty) can handle numbers above 45 millions, and I cannot understand where is the problem.

Can you please find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: tell us about `sts`.  type, shape, dtype

Comment: I'm guessing that `sts` is an object dtype array (or something that becomes that), that contains integers (among other things).  In such a case `np.log` iterates on the array elements and tries to  call a `log` method, which most objects don't implement.  `np.log` will work with numeric dtype arrays, including `int` dtype, but not object dtype.

Comment: sts type is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> With another similar program it works perfectly (and has the same type). Here it seems that building the dataframe (the way I did) made some change in value type...

Comment: It seems, printing sts that it has an index on the left side and I can't delete it

Comment: That's how a pandas Series displays.  I don'y think the index is the problem

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `sts` is a pandas Series

```
In [72]: import pandas as pd
```

`log` works for numeric series:

```
In [73]: ts = pd.Series([1,2,3])
In [74]: np.log(ts)
Out[74]: 
0    0.000000
1    0.693147
2    1.098612
dtype: float64
```

even `None` doesn't bother it

```
In [75]: ts = pd.Series([1,2,3,None])
In [76]: np.log(ts)
Out[76]: 
0    0.000000
1    0.693147
2    1.098612
3         NaN
dtype: float64
```

but put a string in the Series, and you get a object dtype Series/array:

```
In [77]: ts = pd.Series([1,2,3,'astr'])
In [78]: np.log(ts)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'log'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-78-b583cbb218e4>", line 1, in <module>
    np.log(ts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2032, in __array_ufunc__
    return arraylike.array_ufunc(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py", line 364, in array_ufunc
    result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*inputs, **kwargs)
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int which has no callable log method

In [79]: ts
Out[79]: 
0       1
1       2
2       3
3    astr
dtype: object
```

Comment: How can I turn sts into the correct type? The matter is that if I print sts it igives a numeric series (about 600 numeric values, and on the left a sort of index from 1 to 600), so maybe it fails to see them as the correct type for some reason I don't understand.

Comment: Can you add `sts.head` to your question?

Comment: I apologize but I can’t understand the request. Should I add sts.head to the code?